# Sitecore User Group - Budapest #5

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**About the event:**

The next Hungarian Sitecore User Group has been announced! There will be two topics:

- From Privacy by Design and by Default to General Data Protection Regulation - Peter Procházka (@Avanade/Accenture)
- Helix in practice and Helix.Skeleton demo - Tamás Tárnok (@Allwin Informatika)

Free discussions, pizza, drink and beer after the presentations.

**When (UTC):** Tuesday, June 26, 2018 6:00 PM

**Where:** Accenture Hungary, Bence utca 1., Budapest

**[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Budapest/events/251226684/)**

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins in 2 days